# Comunicación Python con OMRO, ¿Cómo leo y escribo datos de un array?

Tags: python

Estoy realizando la comunicación entre un PC y un PLC OMRON NJ. Para ello estoy utilizando código Python, he llegado al punto que soy capaz de leer todo tipo de datos pero a la hora de escribir los datos en el PLC tengo problemas con los de tipo array.

Leo un array entero desde el PC, pero a la hora de escribir el array entero en el PLC me da error. Si voy escribiendo los datos del Array uno a uno no tengo problemas pero quiero escribir todo el array a la vez.

El código es el siguiente:

```
import socket
import time
import cpppo
import numpy as np
from cpppo.server.enip import client
plc_ip_address                  = "192.168.250.210"
timeout                         = 5.0
import logging

logging.basicConfig( **cpppo.log_cfg )

Tag_Real_Valor = 4.0
Tag_Int_Valor = 2
Tag_String_Valor = "Hola"
Tag_Array = 5
Tag_Name_INT = "Python_INT"
Python_Array_INT = ['Int0','Int1','Int2','Int3','Int4','Int5',
                   'Int6','Int7','Int8','Int9']
Python_Array_INT[0] = 9
Tag_List = [9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
Tag_Array = np.array(Tag_List)




lectura = False

if lectura == False :
    #Formato de escritura de Tags
    tags = ["Python_REAL=(REAL)%f"%(Tag_Real_Valor),
            "Python_INT=(INT)%s"%(Tag_Int_Valor),
            "Python_STRING=(STRING)%s"%(Tag_String_Valor),
            "Python_Array_INT[1]=(INT)  %s"%(Tag_Array[1])]
else:
    #Formato de lectura de Tags
    tags = ["Python_REAL","Python_INT","Python_STRING","Python_Array_INT"]

while True: 
    try:
        with client.connector( host=plc_ip_address, timeout=timeout )  as conn:
            operations          = client.parse_operations( tags )
            failures,replies    = conn.process(operations=operations, timeout=timeout )
        for rpy in replies:
            print (rpy)
    except Exception as exc:
       print ("EtherNet/IP I/O Failed: %s" % ( exc ))
    time.sleep( 1 ) #Esperamos 1 sg antes de reconectarnos.
```

Comment: ¿Nos diras el error o tenemos que adivinarlo primero?

Comment: Como te dice @CandidMoe, sin ver el error no podemos saber qué problema tienes. Porque supongo que los errores se obtienen de la variable `failures` y no a través del sistema de excepciones.